# Assigning values to multiple names

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, iterable-unpacking

I have seen many Python snippets where they write something like this:

```
labels, features = targetFeatureSplit(data)
```

or something like

```
ages_train, ages_test, net_worths_train, net_worths_test = train_test_split(ages, net_worths, test_size=0.1, random_state=42)
```

How are they assigning these values?

Comment: I'm sorry, but what exactly do you not understand? You should look at what the method on the right side returns

Comment: This is *"iterable unpacking"*, `targetFeatureSplit` evidently returns an iterable of length 2 (probably a tuple, `return one_thing, another`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you have a function that returns two values like so:

```
def example():
    return 'alice', 'bob'
```

You can then call this function and set it to the variable `test`.

```
test = example()
```

where test is a tuple of 'alice' and 'bob'.

You can instead assign what the function returns to two variables instead, for example,

```
a, b = example()
```

where a is 'alice' and b is 'bob'.

To answer the last bit of your question - if a function does not have a return keyword in it, then it will return `None` when the function completes. Therefore for variable assigment you can only set one variable equal to what this function returns.

Comment: Thanks that helps !

Comment: Glad to hear it! It would be great if you could accept the answer provided it answers your question. ;)